# pip does not detect user-installed packages after upgrading system python?

Tags: python, fedora, package-management, pip, dnf

I use Python on my Fedora KDE (x64) PC. I used to have Fedora 25, and I had installed Python 3.5 using `sudo dnf install python3` and several packages like `numpy` and `scipy` using commands like `sudo dnf install python3-numpy`. Now not all the suitable packages or versions were available on fedora repositories, so those alone I installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` via `pip3 install <packagename> --user`.

Fast forward, and I upgraded Fedora to version 28, during which `python3` had been upgraded to version 3.6. All the other `python3-*`packages have also been suitably upgraded. Now pip3 does not recognise any user-installed packages as in `pip3 list --user`, returning no output at all. But the `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` directory still exists and has a bunch of packages.

Now I am not sure what I should do....

- I can maybe delete the contents of `site-packages`, if I knew exactly what can be deleted? Then I can set about re-investigating what packages really need to be installed via pip now.
- I can maybe rename the `~/.local/lib/python3.5` to `~/.local/lib/python3.6`?
- Some other way to make pip import the contents of the old user-installed python packages?

I am kind of lost on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

That should be a pretty easy thing to do if you still have Python 3.5 around:

```
$ pip3.5 list --user --format=freeze | xargs pip3.6 install --user
```

will reinstall all the user-site packages for Python 3.6. Things get a little bit more complicated when the old Python installation is gone (so no `pip3.5` in your case), but still nothing you can't manage. First of all, check that the user site still exists so you have something to work with:

```
$ find ~/.local -type d -name "site-packages" | grep python3.5
/Users/hoefling/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Now use `pkg_resources` to list the distributions available in that user site:

```
$ find ~/.local -type d -name "site-packages" | grep python3.5 | xargs python3.6 -c "import pkg_resources, sys; print(' '.join((f'{pkg.project_name}=={pkg.version}' for pkg in pkg_resources.find_distributions(sys.argv[1]))))"
wheel==0.30.0
```

The user site dir will be piped to Python code line that will scan the dir using `pkg_resources.find_distributions` function (see [Getting or Creating Distributions](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#getting-or-creating-distributions) section in the docs) which is the same one that `pip` uses under the hood, IIRC. I just added some formatting so you can then pass the output to the new `pip3.6` in the last iteration of extending the one-liner. The full one-liner is:

```
$ find ~/.local -type d -name "site-packages" | grep python3.5 | xargs python3.6 -c "import pkg_resources, sys; print(' '.join((f'{pkg.project_name}=={pkg.version}' for pkg in pkg_resources.find_distributions(sys.argv[1]))))" | xargs pip3.6 install --user
```

`pkg_resources` is part of the `setuptools` package and should be already preinstalled (at least this is the case when using the installers from https://www.python.org/downloads/). If not, install `setuptools` first:

```
$ dnf install python3-setuptools
```